# ComponentDidMount is not being called - very simple app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lifecycle

I used create-react-app to create this very simple app. ComponentDidMount is never invoked.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  ComponentDidMount() {
    console.log("MOUNTED");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hi Lol</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method names are case sensitive, so you should start with a lowercase: `componentDidMount` instead of `ComponentDidMount`.

Comment: Man, that was easy. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, I'd appreciate if you could mark it as the right answer.

Comment: This is most likely the cause. I assume the component is being imported into a HOC with reactDOM as well.